# Artin algebra problem.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Taken From Artin algebra  book Page No : $221$ question $2.1$:

> Determine the centralizer and order of the  conjugacy class of the matrix 
>    $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ in $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$

**My attempts :** I know  that  centralizer  will be $\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\0 & a\end{pmatrix},$ where  $a \neq 0$ and $\text{Order}(GL(2,5))=(5^2-1)(5^2-5)=480$

As I'm confused  how can I find the order  of  conjugacy class..

Any hints/solution  will appreciated

Comment: The centraliser of a matrix $A$ will always have $A$ as an element.

Comment: @jasmine How did you get $Order(GL(2,5))=(5^2−1)(5^2−5)=480$?

Comment: @user35687 $24 \times   20 = $?

Comment: @jasmine sorry I wasn't clear. How did you get $(5^2-1)(5^2-5)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $$C\Bigg(\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0& 2 \end{pmatrix}\Bigg)=\Bigg\{ \begin{pmatrix} a&0\\0& d \end{pmatrix} \in GL(2,\Bbb{F}_5): ad\neq 0 \;\;\text{in} \;\;\Bbb{F}_5\Bigg\}$$

[Check it! If it is wrong, kindly let me know]

---

Hint for the second one: $$\vert cl(A)\vert=\vert G:C(A)\vert$$ where $cl(A)$ denote the conjugacy class of $A$ and $C(A)$ denote the centralizer of $A$.

Comment: ..@Chinnapparaj...one more  doubt   how can  i find  the   order  of $C(A) $?

Comment: Count all possibilities of $a$ and $d$

Comment: that  mean  here  $\mathbb{F_5}$...i mean  here  only 5 element will be there that   is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$..how  can i  count that  $ad \neq 0$..as  im not  getting in my  head

Comment: There are five choices for $a$. But $a=0$ is not allowed, because of invertibility. so we have four choices for $a$. similarly for $d$.

Comment: that  mean  we  have  total 8  choice  ... am  i right ??

Comment: No. sixteen choices!

Comment: oks  ya ..permuatation,,,,i gots it   @ chinnapparaj,,thanks  u